# iOS adds new preferred language when installing my 3rd party keyboard

Tags: ios, localization, custom-keyboard

I have an iOS app implementing a 3rd party keyboard to iOS. The app is localized has a base language which is **English** and one additional language which is **German**.

**My customer reported me following behaviour (which I can reproduce):**

E.g. they are coming from Spain and have only configured **Spanish** language on their iPad. Because I have not localization for Spanish, they want to use the app in **English**.
But if they install my app and than my keyboard...

(1) Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboards -> Add my 3rd party keyboard

... iOS automatically adds German to their **Preferred Language Order**:

**(Settings -> General -> Language & Region -> Preferred Language Order)**

[image]

**Now to the problem:**

As described here in this [Apple Documentation QA1828](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1828/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014938), when using my app, iOS checks if the preferred languages contains a language which is localized by the app and only if this was not successful it will take the base language (in my case **English**).
But because my app implements **German** and **German** is now the second preferred language, my app appears in **German** and not as expected by the user in **English**.

This is what my localization configuration in XCode looks like:

[image]

[image]

***What's the reason that iOS adds a new preferred language after adding my 3rd party keyboard?***

***And could this be a new behavior of iOS 12? Because before nobody reported about this kind of problem.***

**UPDATE 05.11.2018:**
I created an TSI at Apple and they answered me that I should create a bug report about this. Not sure if this will help but I did it and waiting for some answer.